# I feel little stings in the sea

Tags: sea

Yesterday  I went to the beach when I get in the water everything was fine the water not cold the sea very clear. Then I started feeling little stings at all my body.I thought it was  my idea. When I went home I saw all my body it was full of little stings they don't hurt  but I want to scratch them. Pls tell me cause I don't know what are these.

Comment: Where are you in the world? This could be small, nearly translucent jellyfish. I have swum through areas filled with them while surfing southern Baja Mexico.

Comment: In 1989 I was with my parents and sisters at Lago di Garda (Lake Garda) and we had exactly this experience.  We called it "Garda-aaltje" (literally Garda-eal) but to this date I have no clue what it was.  I was almost 4 years old at the time.

Comment: You really need to specify a location.

Comment: Could be jelly fish larvae they are generally found in "blooms" and are nearly microscopic. They have the same stinging capabilities as they grown up family but on a much smaller scale and can easily get caught up in clothing.